# Intellij exploded deploy to JBoss EAP

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, intellij-13, intellij-14

I would like to deploy a maven based multi project to Jboss EAP. According to several article I configured output directory to end with ear, like: `C:\project\module-ear\target\module-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear`. Ear project contains a war and jar projects
First deploy works fine, although I'm not able to refresh classes and resources directly. If I modify something in war project, I cannot see deployed.